# "all" vs "all of"

Tags: prepositions, determiners, predeterminers

What's the difference between these two sentences?

1. He ate all his food
2. He ate all of his food

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant difference here, the meaning is the same. "He ate all of his food" is perhaps slightly more formal, but not by much.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the sentences are identical and convey the same meaning.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all?q=All

Answer (score 0):

According to The Free Dictionary: If you want to say something about the whole of a thing, you use all or all of, followed by the, this, that, or a possessive determiner, followed by an uncountable noun or the singular form of a countable noun.

So Kshitij Singh's answer is correct. The use of "of" is optional, and we normally drop it in such a sentence.